# iOS html text is not working properly in attributed string

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, swift, string

I'm trying to make part of text inside the label - bold. Here is a html code I'm using:

```
<style>body{line-height: 0;}</style><font face=\"Calibri\"><b>Get moving!</b> (and Sync to see your points.)</font>
```

But it's making all text bold. The same thing if HTML is using `<b></b>` tags. It will make all text regular.
Seems that it's checking only beginning.

Can anyone help me with that?

I'm using `NSAtributedString` for showing HTML text. Want to admit that it's working fine in HTML online editors.

Comment: Check my answer Volodymyr

Answer (score 1):

[image]Try this:

```
 NSString *description = @"<style>body{line-height: 0;}</style><font face=\"Calibri\"><b>Get moving!</b> (and Sync to see your points.)</font>";
    self.lblDescription.attributedText=[self getData:description];

//Convert HtmlString to string
-(NSAttributedString *)getData:(NSString *)str
{
    NSData *stringData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
    NSAttributedString *decodedString;
    decodedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:stringData
                                                     options:options
                                          documentAttributes:NULL
                                                       error:NULL];
    return decodedString;
}
```

Comment: Problem already found. It was not in HTML. your code works fine.

Comment: @Volodymyr Please check screenshot. It's working well.

Comment: Don't copy and post the answer once I post my answer with screenshot.

Comment: I didn't copy paste any one's screenshot. I added that screenshot only as a reply to Volodymyr's comment.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.I tried sample one for your question.I got and it works fine.

```
NSString *strHTML = @"<style>body{line-height: 0;}</style><font face=\"Calibri\"><b>Get moving!</b> (and Sync to see your points.)</font>";
NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[strHTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
lblHTMLString.attributedText = attrStr;
```

The Output Screenshot is

[image]

Comment: I already found where was a bug. It was not relevant to HTML.

Comment: Above my answer is the perfect one for making bold text of body part.I checked in html online editor first.After that only I tried.Now it works fabulously.

Comment: Actually not as perfect. The reason for it is because posting HTML into NSAttributedString causes to work WebKit, which causes huge delays for UI. It's just easier to write, that's why I choose it.

Comment: If you have been asked the question " html string for webkit or dispaly the html string in webkit",I would be the first person give the solution.But you asked to display the html string in label with your exact output.

Comment: You are telling that it's best solution. It's not the best, previous answer have the same one and I previously commented as it's not working for me.

Comment: As well I wrote that I'm using Attributes to set HTML into, and it works fine, just not working to set it partly. My code is almost the same as previous two.

Comment: I tried his answer first but it showed the all text as bold.Also you commented that in Bhakti answer.My answer is best among other posted the answer to your question.Don't off to be the topic.I gave exact answer which what you have asked in your question.

Comment: both of answers are the same, he provided screen as well. Only difference is used encoding. I asked to help solve me why it makes all text bold, but not to show me how to post HTML into NSAttributedString. I gave necessary information what I'm using and that it works fine with HTML. There is no other way to post HTML inside the NSAttributed string to work properly, so we have the same code.